# In Hibernate Envers is it possible to query ALL entities for a given revision?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm looking at [Hibernate Envers](http://jboss.org/envers) to solve two problems for me.  First is auditing, fine.  Second is the ability to roll-back a change made in a revision.  This will be implemented by

- Finding all the entities modified in a revision
- Finding the corresponding previous version of each entity
- Creating new versions that effectively reverse the changes made (new->delete,delete->new,update->update)
- Commit new objects

However I can't see a way of querying the list of entities for a particular revision.  There's a method that does it at a class level but not a global level.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean to query list? Query table -

[http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/query/AuditQueryCreator.html#forEntitiesAtRevision(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Number)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/query/AuditQueryCreator.html#forEntitiesAtRevision%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Number%29)

```
forEntitiesAtRevision(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Number)
```

Query list - implement filtering in java code.

Revision number is a transaction number. It is not a version of an entity number. It is a number representing version of an entity in transaction.

If you need to find list of entities revision than you can iterate over list of entities and find Revision of each from the list by query `forEntitiesAtRevision(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Number)`